# Use JQuery to select multiple list item values on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list similar to this (with an arbitrary amount of li's):

```
<ul>

 <li>
  <div class="box">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Product 1</td>
     <td><input type="hidden" class="hiddenid" value="5" /></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" value="yes" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </li>


 <li>
  <div class="box">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Product 2</td>
     <td><input type="hidden" class="hiddenid" value="6" /></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" value="yes" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </li>


</ul>

<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

and I need to use JQuery to loop through each item and collect the #hiddenid value for each item with a checked checkbox, once #submit is clicked (eventually I will pass this string to a php page and onto a database).

This is my attempt at the JQuery, however being a relative beginner (i.e. noob) I am very lost...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".arrow").click(function() {

    var id = $.each("#stockyesno:checked").closest(".box").find(".hiddenid").val();

    alert(id);

  });


});
</script>
```

I am hoping there is a way to correct the traversing of my id variable so its not more complicated...

I have simplified the question, but I'm sure if this can be answered I can scale the answer to my more complicated code.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: A table, inside a DIV inside a LI? Why?

Comment: @Matt Ball that was a error in translation, I assure you :)

Comment: @SLaks thanks, I've made the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to write

```
var ids = $(".stockyesno:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).closest(".box").find(".hiddenid").val();
}).get();
var idString = ids.join(',');
```

This code uses a normal jQuery call to get the checked elements, then calls the [`map` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to convert the set of checkboxes into a set of value strings.
It then calls [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to convert the jQuery object of strings into a normal array.
Finally, it calls the Javascript `join` method to convert the array into a single comma-separated string.

Comment: This is using an ID selector to get a *set* of elements to loop over? :) (same with `#hiddenid`, should be `.hiddenid`)

Comment: @Nick: When I wrote the answer, those were ID's, not classes.  Fixed.

Comment: Superb! Many thanks. Answer worked and is explained very well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this structure:

```
<ul>
     <li> 
         Product 1
         <input type="hidden" class="hiddenid" value="5" />
         <input type="checkbox" value="yes" />
     </li>
     <li>
         Product 2
         <input type="hidden" class="hiddenid" value="6" />
         <input type="checkbox" value="yes" />
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Sime, I'm in the process of developing something that will required the table structure later on, I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to determine which Product's checkbox has been selected, there are simpler ways.

For example, if your checkbox fields looked like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product_id_1" id="product[1]" value="yes" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product_id_2" id="product[2]" value="yes" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product_id_3" id="product[3]" value="yes" />
```

You'd then be able to use the names and their values upon submitting to the server. For example, if you selected the first and last checkboxes, you'd have URL parameters product_id_1=yes and product_id_3=yes to work with.

Simpler still:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product_id" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product_id" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product_id" value="3" />
```

When all of these checkboxes are selected, the value of the product_id URL parameter will be 1,2,3. If only 2 and 3 were selected, the value would be 2,3. Selecting just the first checkbox would result in a value of 1.

It's worth pointing out that in your example code you have duplicate ID's on the hidden fields. This might be an oversight because you were trying to create simple sample code. If not, this fact will certainly complicate your problem. Element ID's must be unique.

Comment: Just noticed that you edited the ID attributes to be classes - so my last comment is no longer relevant to your question, but worth keeping around I suppose.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I didn't think of assigning each checkbox a unique id, which would be possible since each li has one, however is the problem of selecting with JQuery once submit is pressed still not present? What is the URL parameter?

Comment: As I understood it, you were using jQuery to help gather the values that you would then use as part of the submit. If your only goal is to submit selected checkboxes and their product id's, my suggestions should do the trick without having to use jQuery.

Comment: If you still want to use jQuery to get the selected checkboxes in my example, you could use $("input:checked") to get the elements that are checked.